# Solve $x=e^{a\frac{\ln(1+b/x)}{\ln(1+b/x)+c}}$ for $x$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, exponential-function

> Solve the following equation for $x$:
>   $$x=e^{a\frac{\ln(1+b/x)}{\ln(1+b/x)+c}}$$
>   where $a,b,c>0$

We can show that $1+b/x=1+b e^{-a\frac{\ln(1+b/x)}{\ln(1+b/x)+c}}$. Thus,
$$\ln(1+b/x)=\ln\left(1+b e^{-a\frac{\ln(1+b/x)}{\ln(1+b/x)+c}}\right)$$

Now, let $y=\ln(1+b/x)$. Then, $y=\ln\left(1+b e^{-a\frac{y}{y+c}}\right)$. Therefore,

$$e^y=1+b e^{-a\frac{y}{y+c}}$$

I don't know how to continue from here. Any idea what is the answer?

**Even if I find the answer in series, that would be nice**

Comment: @robertz Hi, Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: @robertisrael Can you help me with this please?

Comment: I made a typo in my *Mathematica* code... original posting was incorrect (hence deleted).

Comment: @WongAustin Series is fine too.

Comment: The answer cannot be expressed by any standard mathematical function (including special functions). Maybe it can be expressed as a series by applying "Lagrange inversion theorem". I don't know how to post the link. Sorry about that. You can search it from wiki.

Answer (score 1):

This equation is a trascendent equation. There is no formula to solve it.

The best you can do, for given $a=1;\;b=1;\;c=1$ for instance is to look for a graphic solution and/or a numerical solution

To solve $x=e^{\frac{\ln(1+1/x)}{\ln(1+1/x)+1}}$ you plot in the same graph the line $y=x$ and the curve $y = e^{\frac{\ln(1+1/x)}{\ln(1+1/x)+1}}$

[image]

Comment: Just curious, what part makes it a transcendent equation?

Comment: @rb612 like $x^2=e^x$
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_equation

Comment: Thanks. But, I need an answer working for all $a,b,c>0$. It could be series.